# Lazy type registration using Unity App bloc

Tags: unity-container, lazy-initialization

1. Is it possible to registe the type (container.RegisterType()) in such a way that the type gets registered in container when the type is asked for using container.Resolve<> Method.
   I measn someting like Lazy Registration?

   ```
      container.RegisterType(typeof(IType), typeof(ConcreteType));
      var obj = _container.Resolve<IType>();
   ```
2. Is it also possible by doing configuration in config file?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box: No. Unity does quite some pre-processing (like looking up constructors, emitting IL code for fast object creation etc.) at registration time. It does not matter wether you use a config file or code for configuration.

What is your scenario for "lazy registration"? Isn't lazy instantiation enough? I never had a situation where the registration phase was that performance critical.